# Format of "excludes" option in FileSystemProvider.watch function

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to implement [`FileSystemProvider` interface](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystemProvider) (that should work with some external REST API). But I'm not sure about format of `excludes` parameter in `watch` function.

Docs only says...

> **watch(uri: Uri, options: {excludes: string[], recursive: boolean}): Disposable**
>
> Subscribe to events in the file or folder denoted by `uri`.
>
> The editor will call this function for files and folders. In the latter case, the options differ from defaults, e.g. what files/folders to exclude from watching and if subfolders, sub-subfolder, etc. should be watched (`recursive`).
>
> **uri: Uri** - The uri of the file to be watched.
>
> **options: {excludes: string[], recursive: boolean}** - Configures the watch.

I'm thinking about format used in **.gitignore** files with (double) asterisks, like `**/logs`, but I'm just guessing...

And btw can I just ignore these `watch` calls and fire event through `onDidChangeFile` every time, something happens..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `excludes` are typically *glob patterns*, for instance from the `"files.exclude"` setting. There's a few examples for the `FileSystemProvider` API in particular [in this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47475#issuecomment-384710023), for instance:

```js
watch(Uri.file('/path/to/folder', {
    recursive: false,
    excludes: ["**/node_modules/**", ".git/**"]
});
```

[According to the API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#GlobPattern), VSCode's glob pattern syntax is defined as follows:

> - `*` to match one or more characters in a path segment
> - `?` to match on one character in a path segment
> - `**` to match any number of path segments, including none
> - `{}` to group conditions (e.g. `**/*.{ts,js}` matches all TypeScript and JavaScript files)
> - `[]` to declare a range of characters to match in a path segment (e.g., `example.[0-9]` to match on `example.0`, `example.1`, …)
> - `[!...]` to negate a range of characters to match in a path segment (e.g., `example.[!0-9]` to match on `example.a`, `example.b`, but not `example.0`)

I guess you're free to not support excludes in a custom file system provider if you chose not to, but it may confuse users if their exclude settings aren't respected. It may also potentially have a negative impact on performance if the excludes contain a lot of files, depending on how your provider is implemented.